# How can I set the nav to be non-transparent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am new with CSS and Bootstrap.
I try to create nav fixed-top with bootstrap but somehow it's transparent.

I tried to add to CSS !important but it didnt help.
How can I set the nav to be **non**-transparent?

Here my CSS & HTML code:

```css
.myNavbar{
  margin-top: 0em;
  margin-bottom: 1em; 
  margin-left: 0em;
  margin-right: 0em;
  background: rgba(255, 166, 0, 0.623) !important;
  padding-right: 0em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="row myNavbar fixed-top ">
<a class="nav-link" routerLink="/main">home </a>
<a class="nav-link  col" routerLink="/salads">salads</a>
<a class="nav-link  col" routerLink="/galery">galery</a>
<a class="nav-link  col span2" routerLink="/CuntactUs">contact</a>
<a class="nav-link  col" routerLink="/AboutUs">about</a>
</nav>
```

Is there anyone who can help me please...
Thanks!

Comment: _"but somehow it's transparent"_ - You set it to be transparent here `background: rgba(255, 166, 0, 0.623) !important;` so I don't understand the question

Comment: Like I said, I'm brand new with it
I did not know it was a transparent color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
background: rgba(255, 166, 0, 0.623) !important;
```

to this

```
background: rgb(255, 166, 0);
```

or

```
background: rgba(255, 166, 0, 1);
```

to remove the *alpha/opacity* section of the background-color or set the *alpha* value to be fully opaque.

Answer (score 0):

```
background: rgba(255, 166, 0, 0.623) !important;
```

Remove 0.632 from the rgb color and you're done!